# Combine an Array of Keys and an Array of Values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

this is a very simple question but I've yet to find it in the PHP `array` functions.  Does anyone know a clean way to do this:

```php
    $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    $b = [ 1,   2,   3 ];
    $c = array_fill_keys_kindof($a, $b);
    print_r($c);  // would output array ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Would `array_combine()` work? (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: yes, exactly what I needed.  Excuse my not knowing, HTH for someone else.

Comment: This just proves how bad SO search is. I googled your title on stackoverflow.com and the dupe is the *first* result.

Comment: Slack search - awesome.  Google search - great but creepy.  SO search.. did I mention Google? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), it looks like `array_combine()` might work!

Updating your code example, it might be used like this:

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$b = [ 1,   2,   3 ];
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
print_r($c);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
)
```